# Touchpad freezes when I have two fingers on it

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my laptop (coming over from Windows) and I have found that most of my hardware works exactly like it did on windows however I have a soft touchpad and I often put a finger on the left click area while I move the touchpad with my right hand.

On Windows this worked perfectly (I could keep my left finger lightly on the touchpad and use my right hand to move the mouse around) but on Ubuntu as soon as I put two fingers on my touchpad the touchpad does not move around anymore (It starts working again once I lift a finger off). It also works if I actually press my left finger to click but not if I just lightly hold my finger on the touchpad. How should I fix this? I know I have a synaptics touchpad. Thanks.

Comment: What is the model number of your laptop? There may be drivers you need to install and configure since it is a synaptics touchpad.

Comment: I am using an Acer Cloudbook 11, its model number is AO1-131-C9PM.  Threre appear to be no special Linux drivers for it.

Comment: There are several posts about getting chrome book touch pads to work using chrubuntu. Could you trey modifying one of those for your model, or use this link to help? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection

Comment: @Kyle_H Its not a Chromebook, the name sounds very similar but it came with Windows 10 installed and has never had Linux on it before.

Comment: This post sounds promising, possibly applies to you? Its about 14.04, but the solution could be similar. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297290

Comment: I am already using the basic touchpad, when I change it to advanced the touchpad completely stops working, it says I need I2C driver to make the advanced touchpad work, any idea how I can install that?

Comment: Hmm... Try doing "apt search i2c" to see if any packages match, and install them and reboot to test. You could use apt-file to see if any packages provide files matching that name for a long shot approach. Another thing to Try is to Try installing the sensors-lm package and setting up sensor monitoring. The i2c package is a monitoring library I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is very old, but I've been struggling with this too as I do the exact same thing as you when using the touchpad. The only difference is my distro, which is a fresh install of Xubuntu 20.04 LTS.

After searching everywhere, what fixed it for me was following [this site guide](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000150104/precision-xps-ubuntu-general-touchpad-mouse-issue-fix?lwp=rt).

It seems this problem is caused by the synpatics touchpad driver, and to get the desired behaviour we should use the libinput driver instead. I say this by experience, as I tried a fedora 35 XFCE installation, which uses libinput as it's touchpad driver, and this problem was not present.

As some commands of the linked guide are outdated, I searched for updated versions of them, and fortunately I found out that most packages used to fix this problem already came pre-installed with my fresh xubuntu installation (and I imagine this applies to ubuntu 20.04 and newer versions as well, but I'm not sure of it though).

Here are the steps of that guide that I followed, but now with the updated commands:

1. To update and upgrade the system, run

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade -y
   ```
2. Reboot the computer for changes to take effect
3. Enable HWE kernel (in my case this was already pre-installed)

   ```
    sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04
   ```
4. Reboot the computer for changes to take effect
5. Verify if your system has the dual mouse drivers (my system did not, so I skipped this step. You can check how to do it in the step 5 of the mentioned site)
6. Install the libinput driver (in my case I only had to install the libinput-tools, as the other packages came pre-installed):

   ```
    sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
    sudo apt install libinput-tools
    sudo apt install xorg-input-abi-24
   ```
7. Reboot the computer for changes to take effect
8. Block the synaptics driver, by commenting the section with the identifier `"touchpad catchall"` of the synaptics.conf file. Here I used gedit (`sudo apt install gedit`), but feel free to use the text editor of your choice. After you are done, save the changes and exit the editor.

   ```
   sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/*synaptics.conf
   ```

[Image of the file with the section commented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO3tr.png)

9. Now the only thing left to do is to add some options to the libinput.conf file. Open it with

   ```
    sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/*libinput.conf
   ```
10. Find the section which has the following as identifier: `"libinput touchpad catchall"`. Then, between the entries `MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"` and `Driver "libinput"`, add the following lines:

    ```
    Option "Tapping" "True"
    Option "TappingDrag" "True"
    Option "DisableWhileTyping" "True"
    Option "AccelProfile" "flat"
    Option "AccelSpeed" "0.4"
    Option "SendEventsMode" "disabled-on-external-mouse"
    ```

[Image of file with the added options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQJeI.png)

11. And that's it, after saving the file and exiting the editor, reboot your computer and your touchpad should have the desired behaviour. You may want to adjust it's accelaration/sensitivity in the "Mouse and Touchpad" settings of your system, in case it's too slow or too fast.

Note: You can adjust the behaviour of the touchpad to suit your needs. For example, if you want the accelaration behaviour when you move your mouse, that is, to make it go faster depending on the speed of your swiping, then you can write "adaptive" instead of "flat" in the option "AccelProfile". If you want to check what kind of options are available, [check this site](https://www.mankier.com/4/libinput).