# Touch pad of Asus VivoBook freezes after touching it with two fingers

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, multi-touch

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16 LTS on an ASUS VivoBook Max. The touchpad doesn't seem to be working properly. It freezes after touching it with two fingers and the functionality is not recovered when I lift one of the fingers. I can still use a USB mouse without trouble.

I have tried turning off and on the two fingers option in settings > mouse and pad, without any effect.

The Touch Pad is listed among the Xinput devices.

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Telink Trust Primo Wireless Mouse         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FTE1200:00 0B05:0201 Touchpad             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

> **Question:** Have anyone encountered a similar malfunction?

P.D: The question seems similar to this one: [Touchpad freezes when I have two fingers on it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866773/touchpad-freezes-when-i-have-two-fingers-on-it) But it doesn't seems to be the same problem since, in the case of the OP, the touchpad recovers its function after lifting one finger.

Comment: Have you tried with 18.04 or 18.10?

Comment: Not yet. I was curious about this but planing to upgrade to Ubuntu 18 eventually.